# Error Facebook application, permission accept but...doesn't work at first time

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook, permissions

I have a big problem about my database e the permission of my application in facebook.

when the user open the app (index.php) and accept the permission, the app go to another page (game.php)... when the game.php is open, the script check in the database to look if the ID of facebook is already present, if not the database make the user.

when the game.php is open at first time, the page generate this error:

```
OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in game.php on line 67 check1Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'UIDfacebook' account
```

maybe because the ID of facebook is not ready for save in the database, and why? the permission was accept... if I refresh the page, the page will work fine and the database save the ID, username....

INDEX.PHP (REQUEST)

```
<?php
require('client/facebook.php');

$app_id = '***';
$app_secret = '***';
$canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/***";
$canvas_url = "****";

$code = $_REQUEST['code'];

if(!$code){
$display= 'page';
$scope= 'offline_access, publish_stream, user_about_me, user_likes, email'; 
$redirect_url = 'game.php';
$oauth_url    = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?canvas=1&client_id='.$app_id.'&display='.$display.'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($redirect_url).'&scope='.$scope;
$config = array('appId'  => $app_id,'secret' => $app_secret,'cookie' => true,'domain' => true);
$facebook_client = new Facebook($config);

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">top.location.href = \"".$oauth_url."\";</script>";
}
?>
```

GAME.PHP

```
<?php
require 'client/facebook.php';
require('client/databaselogin.php');
///////////////////
$app_id = "***";
$secret = "***";
$app_url = "https://apps.facebook.com/***/";
//Create our Application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $secret,
'cookie' => 'true',
));
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
//Do we have a user?
if(!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=> $app_url));
    //redirect the url to prompt for login and permissions
    } else {
        try{
            //Proced knowing you have a logged in user who's autenticated
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $name = $user_profile['name'];
            $id = $user_profile['id'];
            $first_name = $user_profile['first_name'];
            $last_name = $user_profile['last_name'];
            $link = $user_profile['link'];
            $username = $user_profile['username'];
            $gender =  $user_profile['gender'];
            $locale = $user_profile['locale'];          
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo ($e);
            $user = null;
        }
}


$checkUIDdb = "";
$connection = "wait";

$id = $user_profile['id'];
$username = $user_profile['username'];
$goldDB = "0";
$user_type = "A";

///connect to the database

$connessione = mysql_connect($host, $userdb, $passdb)
        or die("error: " . mysql_error());
    print ("connect");

    echo $connection = "ok";
    echo $id;

///

$fb_id = $user_profile['id'];
$locale = $user_profile['locale'];
$con=mysqli_connect($sdb,$userdb,$passdb,$db);

if ($connection == "ok") 
{
//Checking User Data @ WT-Database
$check1_task = "SELECT * FROM `tabletest` WHERE `UIDfacebook` = " . $fb_id . " LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$check1_res = mysqli_query($con, $check1_task);
$checken2 = mysqli_fetch_array($check1_res);
print $checken2;

//If User does not exist @ WT-Database -> insert
if (!($checken2)) {
$add = "INSERT INTO tabletest (id,UIDfacebook, username, goldDB, user_type) VALUES ('', '$fb_id', '$username', '$goldDB', '$user_type')";
mysqli_query($con, $add);
if (!$check1_res) {
    echo "check1";
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}
} 
//Double-check, User won't be able to load app on failure inserting to database 
if (!($checken2)) {

    //echo "Excuse us " . $first_name . ". Something went terribly wrong! Please try again later!";

} 
}
    //Close off the MySQL connection to save resources.
 ?>


<head>
</head> 
</body>
    </script>
    MY APPLICATION
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

somebody know what is happen?

Thank you very much

EDIT:

I try to use this script for the GAME.PHP:

```
<?php
require 'client/facebook.php';
$app_id = "aaa";
$secret = "aaa";
$app_url = "http://app.facebook.com/aaa/";

// Create our Application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $secret,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 

//Do we have a user?
if(!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=> $app_url));
    //redirect the url to prompt for login and permissions
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    } else {
        try{
            //Proced knowing you have a logged in user who's autenticated
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $name = $user_profile['name'];
            $id = $user_profile['id'];
            $first_name = $user_profile['first_name'];
            $last_name = $user_profile['last_name'];
            $link = $user_profile['link'];
            $username = $user_profile['username'];
            $gender =  $user_profile['gender'];
            $locale = $user_profile['locale'];


        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo ($e);
            $user = null;
        }
}
echo $username;
echo $id;
echo $user_profile;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>php-sdk example1 </title>
<style>
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

but at the first time, the error is similar?

```
OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session was invalidated explicitly using an API call.
```

if i refresh the page, the problem disappears....

Comment: Is $user is returning something on GAME.PHP once you redirect from index.php ?

Comment: thank you for the reply, but what does it mean? I neet to return some data in the index.php? if some user login from my index.php, why the game.php can't read the ID etc at the first time? but i need to refresh the page? thank you

Comment: What makes you open `game.php` at first time!? since there's no any session `$_SESSION` on it?

Comment: I have reason to ask this. Let me know if you get any $user or in other words iduser first time GAME.PHP  using..$user = $facebook->getUser();

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't understand very well, so, I need to make a $_SESSION on index.php? I don't know, I try for 6 hours with different method, but the result is the same, is working with the first refresh... and where I need to add the $_SESSION and how? for Abhik Chakraborty, I need to remove the // Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();  in the game.php?? thank you very much  for the reply, really

Comment: @Ribis no when u login on index.php after that you are redirecting to game.php, so when u load game.php please check if there is some value in $user = $facebook->getUser(); As you mentioned it does not work first time but if you do a reload it works. So my question was do you get any value of $user first time, you can do a echo to see that, and let me know.

Comment: I try to replace the game.php with another script (I edit the post) but I can't see any echo in the 2° example like: echo $username;
echo $id;
echo $user_profile; so, i don't know what happened, maybe I need to make the acces token on index.php and recall in my game.php? but I don't know how I can do that...I search on internet but I didn't find any tutorial to explain step by step... :( Thank you for the reply